# How does Python's multiprocessing.Queue work under the hood?

Tags: python

How does Python's multiprocessing.Queue work under the hood?

What mechanisms are used to pass the data between processes?

Comment: The source is easily available for ...

Comment: ^ -> [file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py)